# Is that possible to get page name using jQuery in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using WordPress, and I have a contact form (CF7) with a defined ID. I want to automatically detect and insert the page name via the HTML attribute value="" in the input tag using JQuery or Javascript to avoid making the user write it manually. I have found some solutions in PHP but I'm not good at it, so anyone can help me do it (including via PHP)?

Here an example: http://www.tecnoimm.it/property/stabile-di-tre-appartamenti-g0536/ 
As you can see, before the footer here there's a form that automatically detects the name "[Stabile di tre appartamenti G0536]". Hope someone can help me.

EDIT:

I'm sorry for everyone, maybe my question was inaccurate.
I have the following HTML code:

```
<input type="text" name="nomeappt" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" val="12">
```

And this is the JQ code I'm trying to use

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".nomeapt input").attr("val","pagename");
})
```

It doesn't print anything. Furthermore, I'd like to get the page name as value, instead of giving it manually. Hope now everything is clear.
I'm a novice, please forgive me.

Comment: Hi, welcome on SO. You have to write your solution and , if you have some errors, post here your code and then someone may help you.

Comment: So what more do you need you've already got the name of the page.. whats the problem?

Comment: Edited, hope everything will be clearer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it.

```
<div id="nomeapt">
    <input type="text" name="nomeappt" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" val="12">
</div>
```

and

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("#nomeapt input").val(document.title);
})
```

As you can see, I solved giving an id to the div, then selecting the input and giving document.title as value. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

@Antoyosh, even though you did not specify an exact software problem, I'll take the time to give you a few "hints" in the right direction.

You mentioned you are going to use Jquery which is great for this. Here are the steps you should take to get your solution:

1. Use JQuery to get the name of the page using the element selector on an approptiate field. If you do not have a good field to get this value, you should create one in your HTML (perhaps with a `style="display:none"` so that it won't be visible for your end-users)
2. Create a hidden field in your form which you can use to set the name of the page. the *hidden* part is important, since you don't want users to edit this value.
3. Use JQuery to set the value of this hidden field using the `$(selector).val(value)` function.

Ofcourse, this is a quick and brief overview of the most crucial steps you have to take. There are some more and you will encounter some difficulty, but I will not take that joy away from you ;-)

Good luck and have fun!